# Underscore value in Varchar2 type column

Tags: sql, oracle, web-services, xml-parsing

Is the character underscore ( '_' ) acceptable (insertable) in varchar2 type column?

There is a value that needs to be inserted into a varchar2 column of one of my tables, but the value contains an underscore, like 'DOC_OTHER'

The value does not get inserted into the varchar2 column, whereas other values which do not contain an underscore character in their values get easily inserted (as usual).

I'm unable to understand this unusual behavior. Suggest!!

Edit:

Since the value is being picked up from a web service response xml, this is how its done.
The sql code is fine. **All other values are getting retrieved**, plus there is nothing wrong with the path as well.

Looping through the response:

```
begin
    for p in (
            select * from
            ----  some xmlnamespaces of the response  ----
                   columns
                           "DocData"     varchar2(240) path 'path to DocData in response'
                          ,"RepID"       varchar2(200) path 'path to RepID in response'
                          ,"DocInit"     varchar2(400) path 'path to DocInit in response'

              )

    loop 
        begin                                                                        
           insert into pooling_info                                                       
           (session_id, user_id, DocData, RepID, DocInit)                                  

           values(                                                                         
           p_session, p_user, p."DocData", p."RepID", p."DocInit"                              
           );
         end;
    end loop; 
end;
```

If the value of DocData does not contain an underscore character, it is inserted in the table, this is strange but if the data contains an underscore, the value is not inserted!

It does not throw any error. The surrounding values are inserted except for this (DocData) which contains an underscore

Comment: Please, show us the way as you are inserting this value

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `_`. Please post the statements you use to insert the value

Comment: When inserting data, the `_` is just a normal character: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/51164/1 however for a `LIKE` condition the `_` _is_ indeed something special. How do you verify that the value is "does not get inserted"? Maybe your statement to _retrieve_ it is wrong.

Comment: For the sake of "good question" etiquette, how about showing us what you did specifically.

Comment: @pratham 1. Does it throw an error? 2. For a record that is not being inserted, can you just take one sample record and execute the insertion statement (again, is there any error being thrown)?

Comment: It does not throw any error.
The surrounding values are inserted, except the one with ' _ '

Comment: Is there any trigger on the table that removes underscore before inserting?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing out of the ordinary about adding an '_' character(s) to a `VARCHAR2` column.

As others have pointed out, the '_' character is a wildcard so it does have a special meaning when used with a `LIKE` condition.

More than likely, I suspect the problem you are experiencing is either a size issue (e.g. you are trying to place something too large for the VARCHAR2 that you are modifying) or a constraint issue.

Here is an example of modifying a column using the example schema, SCOTT.

```
SCOTT@dev> 
  1  CREATE table EMP3 as
  2  (SELECT *
  3*   FROM emp)
SCOTT@dev> /

Table created.


SCOTT@dev> select empno, ename from emp3 where empno = 7369;

     EMPNO ENAME      
========== ==========
      7369 SMITH    

1 row selected.  
SCOTT@dev> DESC emp3;
 Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  Null?    Type
 -------------------------
 EMPNO NOT NULL NUMBER (4)
 ENAME VARCHAR 2(10)
 JOB VARCHAR 2(9)
 MGR NUMBER (4)
 HIREDATE DATE 
 SAL NUMBER (7,2)
 COMM NUMBER (7,2)
 DEPTNO NUMBER (2)

SCOTT@dev> UPDATE emp3
  2  SET ename = ename || '_BOB'
  3  WHERE empno = 7369
  4  ;

1 row updated.

SCOTT@dev> select ename
  2  from
  3  emp3 where empno = 7369;

ENAME
==========
SMITH_BOB
```

Comment: thanks Patrick.. but this is not what I wanted to know. Please see the edited question, sorry for the delay

Comment: It did sound too obvious (that is why I wanted an example). Like everything we do, some refinement usually is needed.